# angularjs button not displaying prompt

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and was testing a very simple button, but i cannot get it to work. Here is the view

```
<body ng-app="buttonTest">
 <div id="test" ng-controller="TestController">
  <button ng-click="greet()">greet</button>
 </div>
</body>
```

and this is my controller

```
angular.module('buttonTest', [])
 .controller('TestController', ['$scope', TestController]);

 function TestController($scope) {
 $scope.greet = function() {
    alert('yo');
 };
}
```

I have tested it in plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/WTjTnDEpSMi31UW4weI6?p=preview which seems to work fine, but my code created in sublime text does not function at all.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you referenced scirpt file on your page correctly? look at the console, any error there?

Comment: It is referenced correctly, as i have checked the page source and the test.js file is there. I have just omitted the extra html tags, and have referenced the .js file using
    <script src="test.js"></script>

Comment: what messages are in the browsers console?

Comment: I ended up remaking the project from scratch and it seemed to work. Couldn't find the error for some reason, but it seems to be working now

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the HTML snippet in a full HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script> <!-- reference angularjs -->
    <script src="app.js"></script> <!-- reference your controller's code -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test" ng-controller="TestController">
        <button ng-click="greet()">greet</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already had these tags I just left them out to save space in the original post

Answer (score 0):

What i found is everything started working fine when i added the reference to angular JS angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

please check and confirm if its working for you.

Comment: I have added this and unfortunately the button is still dead. When I converted the code into plain js it works fine, but i can't get the angular code to work.

Comment: please provide me the files exactly that you are using so that i can have a look.